# После нажатия на кнопку ,эта кнопка должна блокироваться и второй раз не нажиматься ,что не так?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть кнопка ,которая выполняет определенную функцию

```
 <div id="footer">
            <button class="btn third"  onclick="google.script.run.ConsolidateSheet()">Consolidate sheets</button>
 </div>
```

и есть код js, который должен её блокировать,но почему-то не работает :

```
var element = document.getElementById('footer');
$(".btn third").click(function(){
      element.disable = false ;
    });
```

Comment: посмотрите внимательно что именно вы блокируете. и то - даже не блокируете ибо disable = false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот код не может блокировать кнопку, потому что `element` в данном случае `footer`, а не кнопка. Используйте при клике на кнопке `$(this)` - то есть указание на саму кнопку (только селектор правильно напишите):

```js
$(".btn.third").click(function(){
  $(this).prop('disabled',true)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="footer">
 <button class="btn third">Consolidate sheets</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно так

```js
var element = document.querySelector(".btn.third");
element.addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.disabled = true;      
});
```

```html
<div id="footer">
    <button class="btn third">Consolidate sheets</button>
</div>
```

Comment: только фарш из js и jquery - это жесть, конечно )

Comment: @humster_spb лишь указал на его упущения

Comment: @humster_spb переписал на чистом JS чтоб не смущять

Comment: ну, так значительно лучше ) плюс